# Downloading local json executing twice

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to download a locally generated json with this code:

```js
function downloadJson(data, name) {
    let dataStr = 'data:text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
    var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute('href', dataStr);
    downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute('download', name);
    document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchorNode);
    downloadAnchorNode.click();
    downloadAnchorNode.remove();
}

downloadJson({foo: "bar"}, "example.json");
```

But for a reason it is downloading 2 copies of the same json. Does anybody knows what is happening?

Comment: It only downloads once here. Are you sure you're not running the function twice? Add a `console.log` call so you can see how many times it runs.

Comment: That piece of code works once. I think the problem is where you call that `downloadJson` function

Comment: To me it downloads only once. Perhaps you're calling it twice? Do a quick CTRL+F for `downloadJson`

Comment: Thank you guys, it was a problem with some parallel processing I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling it twice in a process with timers/intervals....